# Possible to Delete Azure Automation Jobs Output

Tags: azure, azure-automation

After an Azure Automation Runbook has completed (or even stopped), it leaves a history of "Jobs" in Azure Automation. I would like to delete this log of completed Jobs, but cannot find anything in the GUI to delete them. Is it possible to delete the list of completed jobs (under Process Automation > Jobs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on azure feedback below, job history is kept for 90 days before being automatically  removed.

https://feedback.azure.com/forums/246290-automation/suggestions/19224634-ability-to-remove-jobs-from-the-jobs-history

Please vote on it if you consider this capability important.